# assert_template fails after switching to Polymorphic Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations

It is probably something silly simple but I simply can not figure it out. Here is my situation: after adding a new db I realized that it would be the best to change an already existing one, so that it now uses polymorphic associations. Of course after I changed it, pretty much everything else went to hell. I managed though to fix all but one minor problem. The integration test now fails and I simply dont know why since the page itself still works perfectly fine...

```
def setup
  @user=users(:michael)
  @clip=clips(:Michi_clip_one)
  log_in_as(@user)
end

test "successful edit" do
  get edit_clip_path(@clip)
  assert_template "clips/edit"
  ....


FAIL["test_successful_edit", ClipEditTest, 2.686249095015228]
test_successful_edit#ClipEditTest (2.69s)
expecting <"clips/edit"> but rendering with <[]>
test/integration/clip_edit_test.rb:13:in `block in <class:ClipEditTest>'
```

Since I really have no idea where lies the problem, I will simply add a few things of which I think that they might be related.

```
Michi_clip_one:
  adress: "nfWlot6h_JM"
  owner: michael
  description: "MyText"
```

.

```
class Clip < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :owner, polymorphic: true
  default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
  validates :adress, presence: true, uniqueness: {scope: :owner}
  before_save { self.adress=adress.split("=").last }
  validates :owner, presence: true
end
```

.

```
class ClipsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:new, :destroy, :edit, :update, :create]
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:destroy, :edit, :update]

  def edit
    @clip=current_user.clips.find_by(id: params[:id])
  end
```

If you need other lines of code to figure the problem out, I'll be happy to add it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok got it. When using polymorphic associations, the fixtures need to be changed a little by adding the corresponding model.

```
Michi_clip_one:
  adress: "nfWlot6h_JM"
  owner: michael (User)
  description: "MyText"
```